# Unable to perform mail merge using Office 2013

Tags: mail-merge

I'm attempting to perform a mail merge on a simple contact object in Salesforce, but I'm receiving the following error:

```
Exception: CMMHost::GenMailMerge:Exception
The mail merge feature is only support(sic) for Office 2000 and above.
```

I'm currently running Office 2013 on Windows 7. Has anyone experienced this or been able to run mail merges from a similar environment?

Comment: It does look like it's a known issue: http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000007608&language=en_US but unsure either of the solutions in that article match your exact environment. But worth a look.

Comment: @MarkMasterson I am also getting the same exception. And I am using Windows 8 with IE 11. Additionally, I am also getting another error of type:
**Exception:CMMHost::GenMailMerge:Exception 
Object variable or With block variable not set**

Comment: I am afraid Salesforce has abandoned this product... I am looking for an alternative, but haven't found it yet.